# ¿ Cómo actualizar una tabla en una base de datos en SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, sintaxis

Necesito realizar una actualización de una tabla de una base de datos, el SQL me dice que el código lo tengo mas escrito, pero no encuentro en donde tengo el error.

```
public function actualizar($db){
 $comandoSql = "UPDATE ciudades SET nombre ='".$this->nombre."',
   departamentos_idDepartamento =".$this->idDepartamento." WHERE idCiudad =".$this->idCiudad;
 $resultado = $db->ejecutarConsulta($comandoSql);
 return $resultado;
}
```

El error que me aparece en el navegador es:

> **Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

Comment: Ahora me aparece este error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\departamentos\clases\Ciudades.php on line 39

Comment: La linea 39 es la linea del $comandoSql, antes mencionada

Comment: Ahora este: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.bogota.}, departamentos_idDepartamento ={.4.} WHERE idCiudad ={.}' at line 1

Comment: Haz un echo de $comandoSql para ver la senténcia completa y pégala por ejemplo en phpmyadmin para ver si allí funciona. De todas formas, te aconsejo que averigues sobre SQL Injection, pues parece que alguno de los valores contiene carácteres que rompen la SQL.

Answer (score 0):

lo que podrías verificar sería lo siguiente:

1. Que funcione la sentencia completa directamente desde la base de datos. 
   Ejemplo:

   UPDATE ciudades SET nombre ='nombreCiudad',departamentos_idDepartamento = 5 idCiudad = 2;
2. Validar que el campo departamentos_idDepartamento e idCiudad no sean de tipo varchar, por que sino tendrías que incluirlos con comillas simples. Si, es así, la sentencia sería algo así:

   $comandoSql = "UPDATE ciudades SET nombre ='".$this->nombre."',
          departamentos_idDepartamento ='".$this->idDepartamento."' WHERE idCiudad ='".$this->idCiudad';
3. Validar nombres de campos y de tabla sean correctos.
4. Validar que los parámetros que estás pasando a la consulta si estén correctos. $this->idDepartamento y $this->idCiudad e imprimir la sentencia $comandoSql.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un error en la versión de [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) que estás utilizando.
Recuerda que **Xampp** incluía **MySQL** hasta la versión 5.6.12
Tal vez deberías actualizar a una versión más reciente de [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html)